# Optimal time calculation algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I started playing an online game, and I'm wondering how to calculate the optimal resource to choose to get the minimum time.
So basically there are 4 resources (say w, x, y, z), which I have a stable income of (for example w = 14, x = 20, y = 17, z = 19), a building takes a certain amount of each resource (for example 70, 50, 40, 100), I can choose to get a boost in one type of income (say 40 to any resource I choose), I can change the boosted resource at any time. 
I was thinking about it but couldn't come up with a good algorithm to calculate what resource to choose and at what time to change the boosted resource so I can get the required resources as fast as possible.

Comment: Couldn't you just apply the boost to the resource that will take the longest to complete?

Answer (score 3):

These kinds of problems are usually solved by [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). If you could ask a more precise question with an example strategy (even a suboptimal strategy would be great), an example could be shown.